# Content-Security-Policy HTTP header not working properly for script-src

Tags: javascript, http, security, browser, http-headers

I am following [Google's strict CSP policy](https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html) for my CSP header, and I am properly adding the nonce, however I keep getting this error in the browser for my scripts:

> Refused to load the script
>   'http://localhost:8080/client/dist/inline.6e0c61259742e86be1dd.bundle.js'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "script-src nonce-XVlBzgbaiCMRAjWwhTHctcuAxhxKQFDaFpLSjFbcXoEFfRsWxP
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:".
>   'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based whitelisting is disabled.

As you can see, the nonce matches the nonce in the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/dist/inline.6e0c61259742e86be1dd.bundle.js" nonce="XVlBzgbaiCMRAjWwhTHctcuAxhxKQFDaFpLSjFbcXoEFfRsWxP"></script>
```

This is the CSP header I'm using for `script-src`. The "%s" represents the random generated nonce which will be interpolated before the header is set on the response:

```
script-src nonce-%s 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'strict-dynamic' https: http:;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're not enclosing the nonce value in single quotes -- instead of `nonce-%s` it should be `'nonce-%s'` in your policy.

Since you're using the Google example you probably know about the other directives necessary to make the policy safe (e.g. `object-src` and `base-uri`), but just in case, make sure to use a tool like the [CSP Evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.appspot.com) to sanity-check your policy when you're done.

Comment: Good catch! Haven't tested yet, but that sounds reasonable. Will look into this more after work and accept answer if it works. Thanks for the evaluator as well. I am using the other two, though.